# Rich text data save as HTML into sql server

Tags: javascript, html, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, yui

I am currently saving my Rich Text Editor's data into database as form of text but i need to save it as pure HTML and i am confused with this that is there any format i have to use in database table or what should i do for saving yui data as in form of HTML?

I am beginner with Database so please provide proper help.

Answer (score 2):

Text with HTML code is still pure text for applications without "HTML interpreter", for example in notepad you see it as normal text, but in the webbrowser it creates for you the HTML document. So you dont have to change your database column type for that.

But i have to mention, that text type isnt the best format to store text, better try out varchar or nvarchar. For further information have a look on this article: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/05/26/sql-server-2005-replace-text-with-varcharmax-stop-using-text-ntext-image-data-types/